# Slow MYSQL Insert to DB MyISAM

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, myisam

I have a file (insert.sql) which has 250k rows like these with no key, no index :

```
INSERT `project_383`.`entity_metrics_build_1` VALUES ('d402afeb4630267f383b99875f37162d', 'ClMaxCycl', '-1');

INSERT `project_383`.`entity_metrics_build_1` VALUES ('d402afeb4630267f383b99875f37162d', 'ClLMethodsCalled', '0');
```

I input it to the my MyISAM table using `mysql -u root -p project < insert.sql`, the total time is 5 minutes.

I see in another thread, people say they can insert millions of rows under 1 seconds. I really don't understand. Can somebody explain for me why my SQL is so slow ?

My Server is 16gb Cpu xeon.

Comment: I would expect this is to do with MyISAM's table locking when inserting... but I can't be sure from looking at your queries they look pretty small..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine them into a single INSERT with multiple VALUES clauses:

```
INSERT `project_383`.`entity_metrics_build_1`
VALUES ('d402afeb4630267f383b99875f37162d', 'ClMaxCycl', '-1'),
       ('d402afeb4630267f383b99875f37162d', 'ClLMethodsCalled', '0'),
       ...;
```

If you look at the file created by `mysqldump`, this is how it does it.

Comment: Agreed.  Or create a delimited data file and use `LOAD DATA` / mysqlimport.